# References about universal extension

Tags: reference-request, modules, homological-algebra

Let $\Lambda$ be a finite dimensional $k$-algebra over an algebraically closed field $k$. $T$ is a tilting module, then for an $\Lambda$-module $X$, I have seen in a material that

"consider the universal extension $$0 \rightarrow X \rightarrow E \rightarrow T' \rightarrow 0$$
with $T' \in add T$. This extension has the property that the connecting homomorphism $Hom_{\Lambda}(T,T') \rightarrow Ext_{\Lambda}^1(T,X)$ is surjective."

I have not seen universal extension before. Could anyone provide me some materials about universal extensions containing the above property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best detailed reference can probably be found in the proof of lemma 2.4. in chapter VIII. in the book Frobenius algebras 2 by Skowronski and Yamagata. It is not called universal extension there but it is explained very well how it is constructed.